# How to use an extra parameter as the z-index on Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, z-index, depth-buffer, topological-sort

I am using a personalized ortographic projection matrix to position my objects, which are all flat sprites. The problem is there is no way to derive the depth of the projection linearly from their positions: it is, instead, the result of a topological sort of them. How can I set the depth of them independently from their positions?

Comment: See if this answers your question. Assign a value to `object.renderDepth`, and make sure `renderer.sortObjects = true`.

Comment: @WestLangley no, this has no effect. :(

Comment: Can you show a _simple_ live example so your question is clear?

Comment: @WestLangley sure, http://viclib.com/lintae (keys: ASDWJK). Notice how the boxes are not drawn in the right order. I'm using a personalized ortographic camera. I can determine the right order already, but I don't know how to feed that info to Three.js. Weirdly, .sortObjects make no difference at all. It is as if my projection matrix overrides it.

Comment: A simple example please, with 3 sprites, nothing else. Also provide an image to show what it is suposed to look like, please.

Comment: @WestLangley there you go: http://viclib.com/lintae/test , source: http://pastebin.com/TkmnB4xU - notice how it does not respect the order. This is the wrong order: o7.no/19CRMSy . This is how it is supposed to look: o7.no/179C29o

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36141/discussion-between-westlangley-and-viclib)

Answer (score 2):

For meshes, you can assign a value to `object.renderDepth`, and make sure `renderer.sortObjects = true`.

This does not work for sprites, however. Sprites are always sorted by their z-coord in camera space, when `sprite.material.useScreenCoordinates = false`.

three.js r.60